# Creating an ID based on factor and filling down with Stata

Tags: stata

Consider the fictional data to illustrate my problem, which contains in reality thousands of rows.

***Figure 1***

[image]

Each individual is characterized by values attached to A,B,C,D,E. In figure1, I show 3 individuals for which some characteristics are missing. Do you have any idea how can I get the following completed table (figure 2)?

***Figure 2***

[image]

With the ID in figure 1 I could have used the `carryforward` command to filling in the values. But since each individual has a different number of rows I don't know how to create the ID.

**Edit**: All individual share the characteristic "A".

**Edit**: the existing order of observations is informative.

Comment: Thanks @timat. I thought about `fillin` and I could have missed something. But for `fillin` you need to specify more than one variable. So, to be more precise I don't want to create observations with missing values for all combinations of char and values, I just want to add the missing characteristics to get 5 rows per ID.

Comment: I don't see a precise specification here of exactly what we can and can't assume. It seems that the existing order of observations ("rows" isn't a standard Stata term) is informative but there is no indication here of an identifier variable.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your comment. That's right the existing order of observations is informative. A naive question: Is there any reason why Stata is using "observation" instead of "row"? Or why not both?

Comment: That's a common term in statistical software over some decades. Stata refers to rows and columns of matrices, but not formally with reference to datasets,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect the change of id, the idea is to compare if the precedent value of char is >= in each rows.

This works only if your data are ordered, but it seems mandatory in your data.

```
gen id= 1 if (char[_n-1] >= char[_n]) | _n ==1
replace id = sum(id) if id==1
replace id = id[_n-1] if missing(id)
fillin id char 
drop _fillin
```

If an individual as only the characteristics A and C and another individual as only the characteristics D and E, this won't work, but it seems impossible to detect with your data.

Comment: Thanks @timat! That's a very good and efficient solution. Let me add that it also works well for my general problem, because all individuals share at least the characteristic A.

Comment: See also data management FAQs such as http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/groups-by-first-occurrence/